# Recommended way to limit CPU usage of a shell script

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, backup, cpu

On Ubuntu 20.04 I'm using the AWS CLI to send backup data from my web server to S3.  While the script works, it consumes CPU usage to the point where other services begin to fail.  This becomes a big problem when a website isn't accessible for up to 1hr while the script sends data.

Is there a recommended way to limit CPU usage of a shell script? The largest backup file is just under 70gigs, so while I suppose I could space out when the files are sent, there are a few that I think would still cause a problem.

Or is something like CloudLinux the only real option here?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Speaking from experience, AWS instances rarely suffer from CPU issues that result in the problems you are experiencing. 95% of the time, it’s an IOPS problem. You can look at limiting this via `cgroups` to ensure your backup process never consumes more than 60% of the IOPS limit for your instance/volume 

Comment: I should clarify that my server isn't an AWS instance; it's a dedicated server at my vendors data center.  I was simply using the AWS command line tool to transfer backup files from DirectAdmin to S3.  I hadn't thought of IOPS being an issue, but thanks for suggesting, I'll look into it.